# Hiding duplicate records based on parameter value, different condition for each parameter value

Tags: reporting-services, duplicates, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 report where there are multiple parameters. I am hiding some columns depending on the parameter chosen and out of that I need to eliminate duplicate rows.
Suppose, If I have a report with columns id, A, B C, D and parameters A,B,C,D (all boolean). if choose parameter A, I just want unique row for id and A column - (I am hiding B,C,D columns by doing column visibility for each columns individually)
If there are 2 records for Id and A, I am eliminating duplicates by checking previous record.

iif(Parameters!A.value=true and Fields!A.value=previous(Fields!A.value),true,false)

I need to accomplish the same for B, C, D parameters.
How do I give multiple conditions depending on the parameter chosen. If the parameter A is chosen, need to check A column against previous A column, but I think that will work only if it is sorted by column A. How do I achieve the same for all the columns.  I tried giving the following, but it is not working

iif((Parameters!A.value=true and Fields!A.value=previous(Fields!A.value) or (Parameters!B.value=true and Fields!B.value=previous(Fields!B.value)) or
(Parameters!C.value=true and Fields!C.value=previous(Fields!C.value)) or
(Parameters!D.value=true and Fields!D.value=previous(Fields!D.value)))
,true,false)

Can someone please advise on how to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: can you post a couple of mock-ups of what you wan the output to look like. I suspect the answer is to filter out the data in the query so it one shows what you need rather than hiding columns but without seeing what you want its hard to tell.

Comment: You could try the Switch Statement.. It's a lot more user friendly in situations like these.

Comment: Hi Harry, could you please explain a bit more on how to use switch in these scenarios. Thank you.